# Scala SBT throws Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1

Tags: scala, sbt

i am using latest SBT tool for my scala code

i am trying to do
compile
test
run

when i do this i am getting following error

```
[debug] Initially invalidated: Set()
[error] Could not create the Java virtual machine.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error] {file:/D:/TestProject/ScalaFX/scalafx/}default-c3c131/compile:run: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1
```

my sbt batch file has

```
@echo off
java -Xmx1024M -jar sbt-launch.jar
```

anyone suggest a solution ?

Comment: Have faced "could not create JVM" was generally related to not enough memory, or too small heap space.

Answer (score 1):

Reduce -Xmx1024M to e.g. -Xmx800M
You are probably running on a 32 bit OS and your JVM can not allocate enough consecutive memory.

Comment: Still i am getting same error i tried with also java -Xms512m -Xmx1024M -jar sbt-launch.jar. I am using WindowsXP java1.6  sbtversion 0.11.2 workign on scalafx.

Comment: I'm getting this error when sbt compile doesnt show any warning or error * $ sbt run throws an exception Exception in thread "sbt-bg-threads-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code returned from runner: 1 at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)